# How to fail publishing of a page in Tridion Event System?

Tags: 2011, event-system

```cs
[TcmExtension("PageEventHandlerExtension")]
public class PageEventHandler : TcmExtension
{
    public PageEventHandler()
    {
        Subscribe();
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs>(PagePublishOrUnpublishAction, EventPhases.Initiated);
    }

    private static void PagePublishOrUnpublishAction(Page page, PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        if (page.Metadata==null)
        {
            throw new PublisherException(new LocalizableMessage(Resources.Properties.DoNotPublish));
        }
    }
}
```

In above method in Tridion Event System I am trying to forcefully terminate the publishing of a page.

While debugging I was able to hit the statement which is throwing the exception, but even then the item gets published successfully. Am I doing it the wrong way, if yes how can I fail the publishing of an item?

Comment: Not sure, that it will help, but you can try to clear in  PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs Targets object (it has setter). It is taken to account during publishing. I think in this case even publishTransaction will not be created.

Comment: What do you see in the message center in the CME and what do the logs show, I.e. do you see you exception message show up anywhere?

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov No I don't see exception thrown by me

Answer (score 3):

When using the following example, I'm perfectly able to stop publishing:

```cs
using Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing;
using Tridion.Localization;

namespace Example
{
    [TcmExtension("ExampleEventHandlerExtension")]
    public class EventHandler : TcmExtension
    {
        public EventHandler()
        {
            EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs>(PagePublishOrUnpublishAction, EventPhases.Initiated);
        }

        private static void PagePublishOrUnpublishAction(Page page, PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
        {
            if (page.Title.ToLower().Contains("do not publish"))
            {
                throw new PublisherException(new LocalizableMessage(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager, "DoNotPublishError", new object[] {page.Id}));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the details of the error it is not showing the ID of the Page, so not quite sure if I set the `object[]` correctly in the `LocalizableMessage` (you might have to play a bit with it, maybe it needs more objects, or the entire Page?).

By using `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager` I can just use the resources I have compiled in my DLL, which would allow for localizing the error message also.

Furthermore, be sure to register the DLL correctly in the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` and restart the `SDL Tridion Content Manager` COM+ application and `Publisher` and `Service Host` services (after deploying the DLL to the right location and updating the config, or after every rebuild of it).

Comment: When I debug this code it hits the break point  but even then publishing is getting successful

Comment: Do you get the error message shown in the UI at all? and what environment are you developing on, is it a single environment or an outscaled one? You might try a reboot just to make sure all references are updated.

Comment: No I am not getting any error message on UI. My machine is 64 bit windows 7. CMS is SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. We have one CMS box and one CDS box. I have restarted COM+, Tridion Services. Even Killed eventing process in processes.

Comment: sounds like something wierd is going on, with this code after registering it in `Tridion.ContentManager.config` and a restart of the COM= and services I directly get a message and the item isn't accepted in the publishing queue, so if you don't get that result, my guess is that you missed out on one of the steps or have a broken system

Comment: Hey I want to confirm one thing. I have added my own resource file in solution and while creating Localizable message object I am passing resource name which I have created, Is this going correct?

Comment: As long as your resource is an embedded one you have everything inside the same DLL, but if not then you would just get another error which should still stop the publishing process

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9774/discussion-between-alokbhatt-and-bart-koopman)

Comment: Hello. I have created the same code and I'm not able to get any error message on UI and the object is sent to the publishing queue. I tried with EventPhase.Initiated, All, processed and TransactionCommited and in any of them I can get the error. I also tried with EventSystem.Subscribe and SubscribeAsync

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the purpose for you want to fail the page publishing using event system. You could just create a simple TBB which will do your job, Instead for writing event handler,

Create a TBB something like Fail Publishing and then attach it to the page template.

```
[TcmTemplateTitle("Fail Publishing")]
 public class FailPublish : TemplateBase
    {
        public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
        {
            base.Transform(engine, package);
            throw new Exception("REASON FOR MAKING THE PUBLISH FAIL")); 
        }
    }
```

you can check for some metadata field before throwing the exception.

Comment: If I have to check page metadata will this TBB attached to a PT will be able to handle?

Comment: yes this can handle, you will have to read the metadata field before throwing the exception or you can also create a CT with this TBB, then create a dummy component and attach it to the page, this way you will have more control. You can do this in various ways, but it all depends on what you are trying to achieve.