# Restrict Publishing by User to Target in Same Publication

Tags: publishing, security

We want to restrict publishing for some content to some targets in one Publication.  We have several Publication Targets within 1 Publication for a few  web applications, including the main site.  For example, the content for an extranet web application is managed in a Structure Group and has its' own dedicated Publication Target.  We should not publish the 'normal' content to the web application target.

Normally I would think to solve this by security, but the users who publish the web app content are the same users that publish the main content.  They work in remote offices and we don't see them or work too closely together.

Sometimes they publish all items to all targets, and this is not too nice for the web apps.

I was thinking of a way to help the users not publish to the web app targets for the main content, or only the web app content to the web app targets.

One idea was a Custom Resolver, but maybe we can use a less technical solution?  Another less technical solution is to rename the web app targets and educate the end users.  But, is there another way we could do this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer you probably don't want to hear is, "Port those structure groups and pages to a separate publication!" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that can be used is event system where you can capture publish transaction verify the structured group and decide whether to publish or not.

The reference for such implementation is available at: [Do no publlish](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2239/how-to-fail-publishing-of-a-page-in-tridion-event-system)

Answer (score 1):

I would have used Publication Metadata to configure which items should go where. You can enable "key-value" pairs via metadata schema to specify which target should pick up which SG or items from an organizational item like folder. Something like:

```
Target A
tcm123;tcm345
```

After adding this metadata to publication, you can either use event system to validate whether the publishing should happen or not for the items in the SG for this target on publish trigger

OR

In your publishing TBBs validate the metadata and do not add items not allowed for the specific publication target.

One downside with this approach would be maintaining the metadata on the publication level, but given your requirements, it seems like that will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The best OOTB solution would be to use Tridion security and educate the users. Custom resolver, like you highlighted, is another technical solution that would work really well.

You could also create new publication inheriting this publication with all of your structure groups (much like a master reference website implementation) and disable publishing at the existing parent level. You can then modify the "Publishable" attribute at the child level for the structure groups that you would NOT want to be pushed for a certain child publications. Assign the needed publication target for each of the child publication.

Authors with permission management right and tridion knowledge may still be able to get around it.